# Common way to select columns in numpy array and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have to write an object that takes either a pandas data frame or a numpy array as the input (similar to sklearn behavior). In one of the methods for this object, I need to select the columns (not a particular fixed one, I get a few column indices based on other calculations).

So, to make my code compatible with both input types, I tried to find a common way to select columns and tried methods like `X[:,0]`(doesn't work on pandas dataframes), `X[0]` and others but they select differently. Is there a way to select columns in a similar fashion across pandas and numpy?

If no then how does sklearn work across these data structures?

Comment: what's the downvote for? Let me know in what sense the question is lacking and I'll try to fix it. Thanks

Comment: why not convert the dataframe inputs to numpy matrices using [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)?

Comment: Yes, it'd be easy to check the instance type and convert accordingly. I'll probably use that. I was kinda hoping that there would be a common way given how tightly pandas is integrated with numpy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an if condition within your method and have separate selection methods for pandas dataframes and numpy arrays. Given sample code below.

```
def method_1(self, var, col_indices):
    if isinstance(var, pd.DataFrame):
        selected_columns = var[var.columns[col_indices]]
    else:
        selected_columns = var[:,col_indices]
```

Here, var is your input which can be a numpy array or pandas dataframe, col_indices are the indices of the columns you want to select.